# List in local working fine but in server works inverse

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm converting a queryset in a list, like this:

```
qs = CreditoPredio.objects.filter(predio_id=self.kwargs['predio_id'])
id_list = list(qs.values_list('id', flat=True))
position = id_list.index(int(self.kwargs['pk']))
```

For example the list is: `[1,2,3,4]` 
And if I print position in local works fine, id 1 is position 0, 2 is position 2 and so on. But when I upload this to Heroku, the list is inversed, 4 is the position 0 and 1 is the last position. Why? Any clue about how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

For the first, I don't see why this would be a problem. What is it you're trying to solve here? Why do you need the ID list ordered?

Anyways, to always get the list ordered by IDs, you can simply use the [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) on your query, to always return the list ordered by the ID number:

```
qs = CreditoPredio.objects.filter(predio_id=self.kwargs['predio_id']).order_by('id')
```

I don't know why you're results are different. Are your local installation the exact same as Heroku? Are the data entered in the exact same order? If not, you can't assume that your local version will run 100% exactly like on Heroku.

Comment: yes, that the weird point, in Heroku I ordered the ID's and now works fine, but in general, question is not about this specific situation, is about why works fine in local but not in Heroku?

Comment: See the last part of my question. Are you using the same database and version locally as on Heroku? Webserver? OS? How have you entered the data to the database locally, and how have you entered it to Heroku?